# Petición post regresa DOM en aplicación AngularJS montada en Node.js con Pretty URLs

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, post, express, pretty-urls

Utilizo la siguiente petición post desde AngularJS para obtener el response en un servidor de Node.js.

**Función dentro de un controlador de AngularJS**

```js
$http.post("/postFunction",{
    key:"text"
}).then(function(callback){
    console.log(callback.code);
});
```

**Estructura en el archivo server.js que ejecuta Node.js**

```js
 var express = require('express');
 var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var server = express();
 server.use(bodyParser.json());
 server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 

 server.post('/postFunction',function(req,res){
    res.json({code:'done'});
 });
```

Mi problema es que la el valor que retorna la petición post me imprime todo el DOM de mi index como respuesta. Básicamente sé que es la ruta de la petición porque nunca entra a la función.

[image: retorna todo el DOM]

Anteriormente estaba funcionando y me di cuenta que empezó a fallar cuando habilite las pretty URLs en angular las cuales me funcionan correctamente
https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: Tu codigo del lado servidor no parece tener problemas. A mi me retorna el objeto JSON correctamente. Podrias elaborar mas tu pregunta con mas codigo del lado cliente?

Comment: Lo más probable que haya ocurrido es que habilitaste el modo html5 en angular pero las rutas que devuelven datos las declaraste después del middleware que gestiona dicho modo html5. Tus rutas no se ejecutan porque ya al cliente le fue enviada la respuesta. Con el código actual es imposible saberlo con 100% de seguridad. Edita la respuesta e incluye el resto del código del servidor.